# How to determine RestartStrategy with Dynamic Supervision

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

If start child spec statically：

```
init(...) ->
    {ok, {{RestartStrategy, MaxR, MaxT},
          [ChildSpec, ...]}}.
```

But if I start child spec dynamically:

```
start_child(SupRef, ChildSpec) -> startchild_ret()
```

How to determine RestartStrategy、 MaxR and MaxT ?

Answer (score 2):

You cant determine RestartStrategy, MaxR and MaxT dinamically neither in start_child nor anywhere else. These are supervisor's attributes (not child's) and you can determine they only in init/1 callback of supervisor.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `RestartStrategy` is a property of a supervisor and not of its children, you could add an extra layer to your supervision tree and have multiple supervisors as children of a *root* supervisor. Each of the *sub-supervisors* would specify a different `RestartStrategy`. You would then add children to the appropriate supervisor.

[image]

Image from [Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/supervisors).